# jQuery doesnt work at all in IE8

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I have read lots of past postings on this subject...
I have tried every "solution", change to **type="text/javascript"**, upgrade it to the latest version, including this header `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` but nothing seems to work.

The site is [testing.quierodecomer.com](http://testing.quierodecomer.com/) 
**NOTE:** I wrote `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />` in the head for testing issues.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
<title>Quiero de comer!</title>
<link href="favicon.png" type="image/png" rel="icon">
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/css/ui-lightness/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.imageZoom.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        padding: 0px;
        vertical-align:bottom;    
    }

    #container {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 360px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align:center;  
    }

    .box {
        position: absolute;
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:black;
        text-align: center;
        border: 3px solid grey;
        left: 50%;
        top: 100px;
        -webkit-border-radius:60px;
        -moz-border-radius:60px;
        border-radius:60px;
        margin-top:-70px;
        margin-left: -200px;
    }

    #box1 {
        background-color:#FFF;
    }

    #box2 {
        background-color:#FFF;
        left: 150%;
    }

    #box3 {
        background-color:#FFF;
        left: 150%;
    }
    .btn1, .coloniaButton{
        background:#ff5d35;
        border:none;
        -webkit-border-radius:10px;
        -moz-border-radius:10px;
        border-radius:10px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        cursor:pointer;
        color:#fff;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:20px;
        padding:5px 10px;
        margin-right:-225px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .btn1:hover, .coloniaButton:hover{
        background:#3f3f3f;
    }
    #tags, #tipoDeComida, #tags2, #city {
        padding:.8em;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        border:none;
        width:350px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        border: 2px solid grey;
    }
    .titulo{
        margin-top: 23px;
    }
    .caja{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .servicios{
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    #ciudadBreadcrumb, #coloniaBreadcrumb{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    #footer{
        text-align: center;
        background-color: black;
        width: 99.2%;
        padding: 5px;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/supersized.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/supersized.shutter.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/js/jquery.paginatetable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/js/md5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/supersized.3.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="theme/supersized.shutter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.imageZoom.js"></script>
<?php 
include("conecta.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fondo WHERE id = 1");
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $fondo = $row['imgFondo'];
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">         
    jQuery(function($){
        $.supersized({
            // Functionality
            slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
            transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
            transition_speed        :   700,        // Speed of transition

            // Components                           
            slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
            slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                    {image : 'admin/uploads/fondos/<?php echo $fondo; ?>', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''}
                                        ]                   
                });
            });     
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#colonia").hide();
     $('.btn1').click(function() {
        $('.box').each( function() {
            if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                $(this).css("left", "150%");
            }
        });

        $(this.parentNode).animate({
             left: '-50%'
         }, 500);

         if ($(this.parentNode).next().size() > 0) {
             $(this.parentNode).next().animate({
                 left: '50%'
             }, 500);
         } else {
             $(this.parentNode).prevAll().last().animate({
                 left: '50%'
             }, 500);
         }
    });

     $('#domicilio').click(function() {
        $('.box').each( function() {
            if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                $(this).css("left", "150%");
            }
        });

        $(this.parentNode.parentNode).animate({
             left: '-50%'
         }, 500);

         if ($(this.parentNode.parentNode).next().size() > 0) {
             $(this.parentNode.parentNode).next().animate({
                 left: '50%'
             }, 500);
         } else {
             $(this.parentNode.parentNode).prevAll().last().animate({
                 left: '50%'
             }, 500);
         }
    });

    $('#colonia').click(function() {
        setCookie("domicilio", "tipoDeServicio");
    });
    $('#ciudad').click(function() {
        var e = document.getElementById("city");
        var city = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        setCookie(city, "puraCiudad");
    });
    jQuery(document.body).imageZoom();

    $('#pager').hide();
    clienteBar();
    $("#crossCiudad").hide();
    $("#crossColonia").hide();
    loadBreadcrumbs();
    getTipoDeComida();
    getCiudades();

    $("#enviarSignUp").button();

    $( "#logInContainer" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 420,
            width: 750,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {              
                "Regresar": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
    });

    $("#afiliarte").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
            height: 350,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {              
                "Enviar": function() {
                    //function
                },
                "Regresar": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },        
    });

    $("#contactanos").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
            height: 350,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {              
                "Enviar": function() {
                    //function
                },
                "Regresar": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },        
    });

    $( "#sugerirRestaurantes" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 350,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {              
                "Enviar": function() {
                    //function
                },
                "Regresar": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
    }); 

    $( "#terminosCondiciones" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 350,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
    }); 

    $( "#signUpContainer" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 320,
            width: 480,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Enviar": function() {
                    signUp();
                },
                "Regresar": function() {
                    document.getElementById("notificationCC").value = "";
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
    })  

});

function logInDialog(){
    $( "#logInContainer" ).dialog( "open" );    
}

function sugerirRestaurantesDialog(){
    $( "#sugerirRestaurantes" ).dialog( "open" );   
}

function terminosCondicionesDialog(){
    $( "#terminosCondiciones" ).dialog( "open" );   
}

function afiliarteDialog(){
    $( "#afiliarte" ).dialog( "open" ); 
}

function contactanosDialog(){
    $( "#contactanos" ).dialog( "open" );   
}

function signUpDialog(){
    $( "#signUpContainer" ).dialog( "open" );   
}

function send(str, flag){       
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else{
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){            
            //callback      
            //xmlhttp.responseText
            switch(flag){
                case "setCookie":       setCookieCallback(xmlhttp.responseText);break;  
                case "deleteCookie":    deleteCookieCallback(xmlhttp.responseText); break;
                case "loadBreadcrumbs": loadBreadcrumbsCallback(xmlhttp.responseText);break;
                case "getRestaurantes": getRestaurantesCallback(xmlhttp.responseText);break;
                case "logIn":           logInCallback(xmlhttp.responseText);break;
                case "signUp":          signUpCallback(xmlhttp.responseText);break;
                case "logOut":          logOutCallback(xmlhttp.responseText);break;
            }
        }       
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();        
}

function loadBreadcrumbs(){
    //Checkboxes
    if(document.getElementById('domicilioBreadcrumb').value == "set"){
        document.getElementById('domicilio').checked = true;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('recogerBreadcrumb').value == "set"){
        document.getElementById('recoger').checked = true;  
    }
    if(document.getElementById('reservacionBreadcrumb').value == "set"){
        document.getElementById('reservacion').checked = true;  
    }

    var str = "printCookie.php";
    send(str, "loadBreadcrumbs");
}

function loadBreadcrumbsCallback(response){
    var arr = response.split("/");
    //alert(response);
    var colonia = arr[0].split("=");
    var ciudad = arr[1].split("=");
    var estado = arr[2].split("=");
    var tipoDeComida = arr[3].split("=");

    if(colonia[1] != ""){   
        document.getElementById("coloniaBreadcrumb").innerHTML = colonia[1]+"<br />";   
        $("#colonia").show();
    }

    if(ciudad[1] != ""){    
        document.getElementById("ciudadBreadcrumb").innerHTML = ciudad[1] + ", " + estado[1]+"<br />";  
    }
    //document.getElementById("tipoDeComidaBreadcrumb").innerHTML = tipoDeComida[1];

    if(document.getElementById('ciudadBreadcrumb').innerHTML == ""){
        $("#crossCiudad").hide();
    } else {
        $("#city").hide();
        $("#crossCiudad").show();
    }

    if(document.getElementById('coloniaBreadcrumb').innerHTML == ""){
        $("#crossColonia").hide();
    } else {
        $("#tags2").hide();
        $("#crossColonia").show();
    }
    //alert(colonia[1]+", "+ciudad[1]+", "+tipoDeComida[1]);
    //getRestaurantes(colonia[1], ciudad[1], tipoDeComida[1]);
}
function handleSearch(event, ui){
    term = document.getElementById("tags").value;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'loadCiudades.php?term='+term,
      success: function(data) {
        if(data == '[]'){
            restaurantes = document.getElementById("content-background");
            imagen = document.getElementById("proximamente");
            restaurantes.style.display = "none";
            imagen.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            restaurantes = document.getElementById("content-background");
            imagen = document.getElementById("proximamente");
            restaurantes.style.display = "block";
            imagen.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    });
}

function getCiudades(){
    ciudad = "<?php echo $_COOKIE['ciudad']; ?>";
    $( "#tags2" ).autocomplete({
        source: "loadCiudades.php?ciudad="+ciudad,
        select: function(event, ui) { 
            setCookie(ui.item.value, "ciudad");
        },
        search: function(event, ui){ handleSearch(event,ui); }
    }); 
}

function getTipoDeComida(){
    $("#tipoDeComida").autocomplete({
        source: "loadTipoDeComida.php",
        select: function(event, ui) { 
            setCookie(ui.item.value, "tipoDeComida");
        }
    });
}

function setCookie(cookieValue, cookieType){
    var str = "setCookie.php?cookieValue=" + cookieValue + "&cookieType=" + cookieType;
    send(str, "setCookie");
}

function setCookieCallback(response){
    switch(response){
        case "puraCiudad":      document.getElementById("tags").value = "";  
                                $("#crossCiudad").show(); 
                                $("#city").hide();
                                break;
        case "tipoDeComida":    document.getElementById("tipoDeComida").value = ""; 
                                $("#crossComida").show(); 
                                $("#tipoDeComida").hide();
                                break;
        case "ciudad":          document.getElementById("tags2").value = ""; 
                                $("#crossColonia").show(); 
                                $("#tags2").hide();
                                $("#colonia").hide();
                                break;
        case "tipoDeServicio":  parent.location='index2.php';
                                break;
    }

    loadBreadcrumbs();      
}

function getRestaurantes(colonia2, ciudad2, tipo2){
    var direccion = document.getElementById('tags').value;
    //var colonia = direccion.split(',')[0];
    //var ciudad = direccion.split(',')[1];
    var colonia = trim(colonia2);
    var ciudad = trim(ciudad2);
    var tipoComida = trim(tipo2);

    var str = "getRestaurantes.php?colonia=" + colonia + "&ciudad=" + ciudad + "&tipoComida=" + tipoComida; 
    send(str, "getRestaurantes");
}

function getRestaurantesCallback(response){
    if(response == "empty"){
        document.getElementById('paging').innerHTML = "";
        $('#pager').hide();
    } else {
        var arr = response.split("|");
        var restaurantes = arr[0];
        var promociones = arr[1];
        var numPag = arr[2]/4;

        document.getElementById("promocionesContainer").innerHTML = promociones;

        $('#pager').show();
        document.getElementById('paging').innerHTML = restaurantes;
        $('#myTable').paginateTable({ rowsPerPage: numPag }); 

        if(document.getElementById('totalPages').innerHTML == ""){
            document.getElementById('pager').style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('pager').style.display = "block";
        }
   }
}

function stripVowelAccent(str)
{
 var rExps=[
 {re:/[\xC0-\xC6]/g, ch:'A'},
 {re:/[\xE0-\xE6]/g, ch:'a'},
 {re:/[\xC8-\xCB]/g, ch:'E'},
 {re:/[\xE8-\xEB]/g, ch:'e'},
 {re:/[\xCC-\xCF]/g, ch:'I'},
 {re:/[\xEC-\xEF]/g, ch:'i'},
 {re:/[\xD2-\xD6]/g, ch:'O'},
 {re:/[\xF2-\xF6]/g, ch:'o'},
 {re:/[\xD9-\xDC]/g, ch:'U'},
 {re:/[\xF9-\xFC]/g, ch:'u'},
 {re:/[\xD1]/g, ch:'N'},
 {re:/[\xF1]/g, ch:'n'} ];

 for(var i=0, len=rExps.length; i<len; i++)
  str=str.replace(rExps[i].re, rExps[i].ch);

 return str;
}

function deleteCookie(cookieType){
    var str = "deleteCookie.php?cookieType=" + cookieType;
    send(str, "deleteCookie");
}

function deleteCookieCallback(response){    
    //Borra el breadcrumb
    switch(response){
        case "puraCiudad":      document.getElementById("ciudadBreadcrumb").innerHTML = ""; 
                                $("#crossCiudad").hide(); 
                                $("#city").show();
                                break;              
        case "tipoDeComida":    document.getElementById("tipoDeComidaBreadcrumb").innerHTML = ""; 
                                $("#crossComida").hide(); 
                                $("#tipoDeComida").show();
                                break;              
        case "ciudad":          document.getElementById("coloniaBreadcrumb").innerHTML = ""; 
                                $("#crossColonia").hide(); 
                                $("#tags2").show(); 
                                $("#colonia").hide();
                                break;      
    }

    getRestaurantes();
}

function setCookieCheck(check, cookieType){
    if(check.checked){
        setCookie(1, cookieType);
    } else {
        deleteCookie(cookieType);
    }
}   

function logIn(){
    var email =  document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password =  document.getElementById("password").value;

    if(email == "" || password == ""){
        document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML = "Ingresa tu email y contrase&ntilde;a";
    } else {
        password = hex_md5(password);
        var str = "logIn.php?password=" + password + "&email=" + email;
        send(str, "logIn");     
    }   
}

function logInCallback(response){
    if(response == "not_logged/0"){
        document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML = "Las credenciales no son v&aacute;lidas";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML = "";
        $("#logInBar").hide();
        $("#logInBarMenu").hide();
        $("#signUpBar").hide();
        $("#clienteBar").show();

        arr = response.split("/");      
        document.getElementById("usuarioIDnombre").innerHTML = arr[1];
        $("#logInContainer").dialog("close");   

        loadColonia();
    }
}

function loadColonia(){
    var str = "getColonia.php";
    send(str, "colonia");   
}

function loadColoniaCallback(response){

}

function clienteBar(){
    if(document.getElementById('usuarioID').value == 0){
        $("#clienteBar").hide();
    } else {
        $("#logInBar").hide();
        $("#signUpBar").hide();     
    }
}

function signUp(){
    var valido = validateSignUp();
    if(valido == true){
        var nombre = document.getElementById("nombreCC").value;
        var direccion = document.getElementById("direccionCC").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("emailCC").value;
        var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
        var nacimiento = document.getElementById("dia").value + "/" + document.getElementById("mes").value + "/" + document.getElementById("anio").value;
        var sexo = document.getElementById("sexo").value;
        var telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;

        var str = "signUp.php?nombre=" + nombre + "&direccion=" + direccion + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password1 + "&nacimiento=" + nacimiento + "&sexo=" + sexo + "&telefono=" + telefono;
        send(str, "signUp");
    }   
}

function signUpCallback(response){
    if(response == "existingEmail"){
        document.getElementById("notificationCC").innerHTML = "Esa dirección de correo ya ha sido utilizada";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("notificationCC").innerHTML = "Ingresa a tu email para dar de alta tu cuenta";
        document.getElementById("nombreCC").value = "";
        document.getElementById("emailCC").value = "";
        password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value = "";
        password1 = document.getElementById("password2").value = "";
    }
}

function validateSignUp(){
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombreCC").value;
    var direccion = document.getElementById("direccionCC").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("emailCC").value;
    var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value; 
    var dia = document.getElementById("dia").value;
    var mes = document.getElementById("mes").value;
    var anio = document.getElementById("anio").value;
    var sexo = document.getElementById("sexo").value;
    var telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;       
    var mydate=new Date()
    var year=mydate.getYear();
    if (year < 1000){
        year+=1900
    }
    var month = mydate.getMonth();
    month = month + 1;
    var day = mydate.getDate();

    if(day > 31 || mes > 12 || anio >= year){
        document.getElementById("notificationCC").innerHTML = "La fecha de nacimiento no es válida";
        return false;
    } else{ 
        //Valida que todos los campos esten llenos
        if(nombre == "" || email == "" || password1 == "" || password2 == "" || telefono == "" || direccion == ""){
            document.getElementById("notificationCC").innerHTML = "Por favor llena todos los campos";
            return false;
        } else {    
            //Passwords iguales
            if(password1 != password2){
                document.getElementById("notificationCC").innerHTML = "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
                return false;
            } else {        
                //Longitud del password
                if(password1.length < 6){
                    document.getElementById("notificationCC").innerHTML = "La contraseña debe ser de al menos 6 caracteres de largo";
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if(comparaFecha(dia, mes, anio, day, month, year) == false){
                        document.getElementById("notificationCC").innerHTML = "La fecha no es correcta";
                        return false;   
                    }
                    else{
                        if(telefono.length < 10){
                            document.getElementById("notificationCC").innerHTML = "El telefono no es correcto";
                            return false;
                        } else {                            
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function trim(value) {
   var temp = value;
   var obj = /^(\s*)([\W\w]*)(\b\s*$)/;
   if (obj.test(temp)) { temp = temp.replace(obj, '$2');}
   var obj = /  /g;
   while (temp.match(obj)) { temp = temp.replace(obj, " ");}
   return temp;
}

function comparaFecha(dia, mes, anio, day, month, year){

    if(anio > (year-18)){
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
        if(anio == (year-18))
        {
            if(mes > month){
                return false;   
            }
            else
            {
                if(mes == month)
                {
                    if(dia > day){
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

function logOut(){
    var str = "logOut.php";
    send(str, "logOut");
}

function logOutCallback(response){
    if(response == "success"){
        $("#clienteBar").hide();
        $("#logInBar").show();
        $("#logInBarMenu").show();  
        $("#signUpBar").show(); 
        document.getElementById("usuarioID").value = 0;
    }
}

function setServicio(tipo){
    setCookie("check", tipo);
}

function redirect(element){
    window.location = element.title;

}
</script>
</head>
<?php
include("indexBackend.php");
?>
<body>
<?php
    //Carga la session
    if(isset($_SESSION['usuarioID'])){
        echo ("<input type='hidden' id='usuarioID' value='".$_SESSION['usuarioID']."' />");
        $nombre = $_SESSION['nombre'];
    } else {
        echo ("<input type='hidden' id='usuarioID' value='0' />");
        $nombre = "";
    }

?>
<?php 
include("getPublicidad.php");
?>
<?php

    //Domicilio
    if($_COOKIE['domicilio'] == 1){
        echo("<input type='hidden' id='domicilioBreadcrumb' value='set'/>");
    } else {
        echo("<input type='hidden' id='domicilioBreadcrumb' value='not_set'/>");
    }

    //Recoger
    if($_COOKIE['recoger'] == 1){
        echo("<input type='hidden' id='recogerBreadcrumb' value='set'/>");
    } else {
        echo("<input type='hidden' id='recogerBreadcrumb' value='not_set'/>");
    }

    //Reservacion
    if($_COOKIE['reservacion'] == 1){
        echo("<input type='hidden' id='reservacionBreadcrumb' value='set'/>");
    } else {
        echo("<input type='hidden' id='reservacionBreadcrumb' value='not_set'/>");
    }   

?>
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;"><img src="images/logoadmin.png" alt="" align="middle" /></div>

<div id="container">

    <div id="box1" class="box">
        <div class="titulo">Selecciona tu Ciudad:</div> 
        <div class="caja">
            <select id="city">
                <option value="San Pedro Garza Garc&iacute;a, Nuevo Leon">San Pedro Garza Garc&iacute;a</option>
                <option value="Monterrey, Nuevo Leon">Monterrey</option>
            </select><input id="tags" style="display:none" />
        </div>
        <img id="crossCiudad" src="images/cross2.gif" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="deleteCookie('puraCiudad')"/>&nbsp;<span id="ciudadBreadcrumb"></span>
        <span class="btn1" id="ciudad">Continuar</span>
    </div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">
        <div class="titulo">Selecciona el Tipo de Servicio:</div> 
        <div class="caja">
            <input type="radio" id="domicilio" name="tipo" value="domicilio" class="selec"/><span class="servicios">A Domicilio</span>
            <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="recoger" class="selec" onClick="setCookie('recoger', 'tipoDeServicio')"/><span class="servicios">Pasar a Recoger</span>
            <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="reservar" class="selec" onClick="setCookie('reservar', 'tipoDeServicio')"/><span class="servicios">Reservar</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">
        <div class="titulo">Selecciona tu Colonia:</div> 
        <div class="caja"><input id="tags2" value="Escribe tu colonia: Ej. Del Valle" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Escribe tu colonia: Ej. Del Valle'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Escribe tu colonia: Ej. Del Valle' ) this.value=''" /></div>
        <img id="crossColonia" src="images/cross2.gif" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="deleteCookie('ciudad')"/>&nbsp;<span id="coloniaBreadcrumb"></span>
        <span class="coloniaButton" id="colonia">Continuar</span>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="footer">
    <span style="float: left;">Derechos Reservados Quierodecomer.com</span>
    <span onclick="terminosCondicionesDialog()" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration: underline;">El uso de este sitio web implica la aceptaci&oacute;n de los t&eacute;rminos y condiciones de quierodecomer.com</span>
    <span style="float: right;"><a href="admin" style="color: white; text-decoration: underline">Login Restaurantes</a></span>
</div>
<div id="terminosCondiciones" title="TÃ©rminos y Condiciones">
    <?php echo $terminos; ?>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Bookmark */
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // add a "rel" attrib if Opera 7+
        if(window.opera) {
            if (jQuery("A.linkBookmark").attr("rel") != ""){ // don't overwrite the rel attrib if already set
                jQuery("A.linkBookmark").attr("rel","sidebar");
            }
        }

        jQuery("A.linkBookmark").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent the anchor tag from sending the user off to the link
            var url = this.href;
            var title = this.title;
            if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
                window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url,"");
            } else if( window.external ) { // IE Favorite
                window.external.AddFavorite( url, title);
            } else if(window.opera) { // Opera 7+
                return false; // do nothing - the rel="sidebar" should do the trick
            } else { // for Safari, Konq etc - browsers who do not support bookmarking scripts (that i could find anyway)
                alert('Desafortunadamente, este navegador no soporta la petición ' + ' por favor, agrega esta página manualmente.');
            }
        });

        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error you got in IE

Comment: Please describe the problem that you have; your question doesn't state what you're trying to do or what's happening.  You may have read lots of articles on "this subject", but unless you tell us what the subject is it's unlikely that anybody is going to read through your code to figure it what it is...

Answer (score 3):

I checked your JS console in IE7 mode and I got the following error :

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
testing.quierodecomer.com, line 215 character 2
```

So, try just to remove the last comma of your function :

```
$( "#terminosCondiciones" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 350,
        width: 450,
        modal: true,
});
```